# how to get last id insert in zend framework 2 with PDO adapter

Tags: pdo, zend-framework2

I'm newbie in zend 2 ,I want to know how can I get last id insert with zend 2,I'm using PDO adapter ,
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old but it was never answered.
If you are using the tablegateway method then this is how you do it.

```
public function getLastInsertId()
{

    $id = $this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue;
    //$row = $rowset->current();

    return $id;
}
```